# Resources overused

Tags: image-processing, verilog

Can anybody help me to optimize this code.I guess the nested looping is taking a lot of resources. The census_transform is not taking much resources but this correlation block is taking 158% of resources.How can I avoid the use of loops.

```
     module correlation(clk,disp_map
);
 input clk;
 output reg [5:0] disp_map;

 reg [7:0] d = 0;
 wire [119:0] census_left;
 wire [119:0] census_right;
 reg [119:0] temp [0:63];
 reg [119:0] hamming;   
 reg en_l = 1;
 reg en_r = 0;
 reg [6:0]prevSAD = 7'h7f;
 reg [6:0] SAD = 0;
 reg BestPosition = 0;
// integer count =0;
 integer j =0;
 integer i =0;
 integer k =0;
 integer p =0;
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------//
 /*always @ (posedge clk)
 count = count+1;*/
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------//
 always @ (posedge clk)
 begin
    if(d==63)
        en_r = 1;
    else
        d = d+1;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------// 
    if(j<=16380)
    begin
        temp[0] <= census_left;
        for(i=0;i<63;i=i+1)
        begin
            temp[i+1] <= temp[i];
        end
        j=j+1;
    end
//------------------------------------------------------------------------//    
    if(en_r)
    begin
        for(k=0;k<63;k=k+1)
        begin
            hamming = census_right^temp[k];
            for(p=0;p<=119;p=p+1)
            SAD = SAD + hamming[p];
            if(prevSAD > SAD)
            begin
            prevSAD = SAD;
            BestPosition = k;
            end
        end
        disp_map = BestPosition;
    end


end

census_transform transform(clk,en_l,en_r,census_left,census_right);

endmodule
```

Comment: to implement looping in Verilog or VHDL, I normally create a state machine so that each step of the program happens in a state.

Answer (score 0):

While your resource usage is not clear, I've got a couple of things here.

- Never mix blocking and nonblocking assignments.
- Why are you declaring different loop variables? A single variable is enough.
- Rather than assigning default values, use reset logic in the design.

Please clarify about which resources are you talking about, your simulator version and which nested looping are to be discussed.

There can many more points, I have listed just a few.